# RegEx: Search string at specified line of (text-)file

Tags: regex

Is there a RegEx-approach to search in a given (text-)file only at a specified line? I'm using the tool "grepWin".

If my text-file was for example:

```
This is the first line apple
This is the second line orange
This is the third line apple
This is the fourth line orange
```

How can I search and find only the string "apple" in the third line?

I also want to search files for strings that occur at specific lines in the file.  Like I am looking for 'Error Foo', but only if it happens in line 4 of the error log.

Comment: Depends on the program/language/framework you're using to apply regex

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: Thanks. The program is called grepWin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a regex approach but you might want to split your text with `split('\n')` (or similar depending on the language).
Anyway you'll have what you're looking for with:

```
^(?<!\n)(?:.*?\n){2}[^\n]*?(line)
```

- `^` ensure we start at the beginning of a line
- `(?<!\n)` is a negative lookbehind to make sure the current line is not preceeded by another one (i.e. we start counting from the first line)
- `(?:...)` delimits a non capturing group. It's not the relevant part of the match
- `.*?\n` matches any character until a line break is met (`?` makes the expression lazy instead of greedy)
- `{2}` is the numer of line breaks you want to count (basically your line number minus 1)
- `.*?(line)` matches any character until the next occurrence of "line"

See here: https://regex101.com/r/JIRkpN/1